# Mirror API Playground not posting to timeline

Tags: google-mirror-api

I believe I've gone through all the steps of creating a (web) client-id for authorizing requests from the Mirror API Playground, yet when I hit the Authorize button, and then Insert a card from a template, nothing is sent to glass.

[image]

I also note that the Timeline tab below is empty.

Web I bring up developer tools, I note that the POST to https://www.googleapis.com/rpc is returning results:

```
[
 {
  "error": {
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Access Not Configured",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "usageLimits",
     "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
     "message": "Access Not Configured"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "gapiRpc"
 }
]
```

Am I missing something in how to authorize the Mirror Playground?

Comment: Your question included your client secret which allows others to hijack your APIs Console project. I recommend you reset it as soon as possible.

Comment: Oops.  Client id deleted.

Comment: BTW - I'm assuming that the security model for Client ID for web applications is that the Client Secret CAN be published in web sites - api calls are protected by matching the referer to the allowed origins?

Comment: Client IDs are ok to make public (check into source control, etc) because they get exposed anyway during the OAuth flow. Secrets, though, should stay secret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the Google Mirror API.

Do this by toggling the switch on the Services panel for your project as pictured here:
[image]. This toggle will only be visible if you have been whitelisted for the Google Mirror API as part of the [developer preview](https://developers.google.com/glass/devprev).

Comment: Oh.  I don't see the Mirror API in my list of available API's so I must not be in the preview.  I'm an Explorer with Glass since Google IO (13) so I thought this would be automatic.  Is there something I have to do to get my account authorized for preview?

Comment: To get into the developer preview, I called the phone number from my original Glass invitation (1-800-GL__-__), and had my original unique order order code.  Just tell the representative that you are requesting Mirror API access, and confirm the gmail account that you are using for development.

You'll then be sent an invite to a Google Group (mirror-api-v1-tt-whitelist).  Members will grant to access to turn on the API in the Services tab of your API console project.